# Using DirectoryInfo with a UNC path

Tags: c#-4.0, directoryinfo

I'm trying to DirectoryInfo to verify whether a UNC path exists, however DirectoryInfo consistency fails over and says the folder doesn't exist, when I can confirm it does in Windows Explorer.

Example

```
var storagepath = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\123.123.123.123\c$\testfolder\test1\");

if (storagepath.Exists)
{ }
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few questions that need to be answered in regards to your program.

Is it running in the same context as the user that you're verifying with explorer?  Is it possible you are, for example, running a console application as a restricted user but logged in as a higher privilege user, etc?

One of the reasons for Exists being false includes not having permission to access the resource.

You could try another method like EnumerateDirectories and see what the result is.  The exceptions and results of EnumerateDirectories are a bit more descriptive than Exists.

Comment: Authenticating the path with a user identity does solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: Hi @wonea, can you share how to resolve this please? I have the same problem, I need to authenticate the user first, but I don´t how to...

Comment: I found this simple Windows Impersonation example library which solved my problem.  Simply call this library and put the commands which need to be ran with a authenticated user, in the using encapsulation.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User